# How to copy DLL file from PC to vs.net`s pocket pc 2003 simulator?

Tags: deployment, simulator

I want to copy a DLL file from PC to vs.net`s pocket pc 2003 simulator, so i use the shared folder of the simulator, but i can not see the dll file in file list of simulator.

How to do it, please ?

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the project's primary output.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: if you need to use an external DLL to be copied along with your code, add a reference to the DLL, and in its properties pane on Visual Studio make sure that Copy Local is set to True. That might accomplish what you're trying to do.